# DrawToBitmapで画面キャプチャを取得した際の画面イメージが実際の画面イメージと異なる

Tags: c#, winforms

C#のControl.DrawToBitmap(Bitmap, Rectangle) メソッドで画面キャプチャを出力すると、タイトルバーのスタイル（テーマ？）がWindows XP?のようなイメージで出力されます。
Windows10だと四角でスタイリッシュに表示されると思うのですが、そうはなりません。
仕様といえばそれまでなのかもしれませんが、その文献も見つけられません。
ご存じの方おしえてください。[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

トップレベルウインドウの非クライアント領域は、DWM(デスクトップ ウィンドウ マネージャー)が描画しています。
DrawToBitmp でビットマップに描画されるのは、Form 自身が描画しているものです。

「デスクトップ ウィンドウ マネージャー」
https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/win32/dwm/dwm-overview
「DWM の概要」
https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/win32/dwm/desktop-window-manager-overviews

あたりを読んでみてください。

下のコードで外観そのままキャプチャできますが、タスクマネージャーなど
TOPMOST な ウインドウが手前にあると写りこんでしまうんですよね。

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Rectangle r = GetDwmWindowRect();
        using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(r.Width, r.Height))
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) {
            g.CopyFromScreen(r.Location, Point.Empty, r.Size);
            Clipboard.SetImage(bmp);
        }
    }

    private Rectangle GetDwmWindowRect() {
        RECT rect = new RECT();
        IntPtr nResult = DwmGetWindowAttribute(
                    Handle,
                    DWMWINDOWATTRIBUTE.DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS,
                    out rect,
                    Marshal.SizeOf(rect));
        if (nResult.ToInt32() == S_OK) {
            return rect.Rectangle;
        }
        return Bounds;
    }

    private enum DWMWINDOWATTRIBUTE : int
    {
        DWMWA_NCRENDERING_ENABLED = 1,
        DWMWA_NCRENDERING_POLICY,
        DWMWA_TRANSITIONS_FORCEDISABLED,
        DWMWA_ALLOW_NCPAINT,
        DWMWA_CAPTION_BUTTON_BOUNDS,
        DWMWA_NONCLIENT_RTL_LAYOUT,
        DWMWA_FORCE_ICONIC_REPRESENTATION,
        DWMWA_FLIP3D_POLICY,
        DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS,
        DWMWA_HAS_ICONIC_BITMAP,
        DWMWA_DISALLOW_PEEK,
        DWMWA_EXCLUDED_FROM_PEEK,
        DWMWA_CLOAK,
        DWMWA_CLOAKED,
        DWMWA_FREEZE_REPRESENTATION,
        DWMWA_PASSIVE_UPDATE_MODE,
        DWMWA_USE_HOSTBACKDROPBRUSH,
        DWMWA_USE_IMMERSIVE_DARK_MODE,
        DWMWA_WINDOW_CORNER_PREFERENCE,
        DWMWA_BORDER_COLOR,
        DWMWA_CAPTION_COLOR,
        DWMWA_TEXT_COLOR,
        DWMWA_VISIBLE_FRAME_BORDER_THICKNESS,
        DWMWA_LAST
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct RECT
    {
        public int Left, Top, Right, Bottom;
        public Rectangle Rectangle {
            get {
                return Rectangle.FromLTRB(Left, Top, Right, Bottom);
            }
        }
    }

    [DllImport("dwmapi.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr DwmGetWindowAttribute(
                IntPtr hwnd,
                DWMWINDOWATTRIBUTE attr,
                out RECT pvAttribute,
                int attrSize);

    private const int S_OK = 0;

}
```